# How Can I Call A Function With Variable Value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

'''

```
operator = input("Enter What You Wanna Do (add/sub/multi/div")
firstNum = int(input("Enter First Number:"))
secondNum = int(input("Enter Second Number:"))

def add(result):
    result = firstNum + secondNum
    return result
def sub(result):
    result = firstNum - secondNum
def multi(result):
    result = firstNum * secondNum
    return result
def div(resukt):
    result = firstNum / secondNum
    return result
```

'''

in this code how can i call all those functions when needed without 4 if statements i tried to add like **operator()** in hopes of it will take value of operator variable and call specific user entered function but it failed can some one give an option

Answer (score 0):

If Someone Wonders The Answer  Ive Been Able To Figure That Out

```
eval(operator+"()")
```

Adding this function willl fix it ;)

Comment: Just as a note: using `eval()` will pretty much never be considered good practice and should be avoided.

Comment: If you think you solves your problem, please  improve your solution and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title you can use `globals()` to return a function based on a string. Here, that would look something like:

```
operator = input("Enter What You Wanna Do (add/sub/multi/div)")
firstNum = int(input("Enter First Number:"))
secondNum = int(input("Enter Second Number:"))

def add():
    result = firstNum + secondNum
    return result

func_obj = globals()[operator]
print(f'The answer is {func_obj()}')
```